# Blank band when setting height of div less than the height of the screen

Tags: ios, cordova

I am working with phonegap for a new project recently. In my app, I want to keep the status bar, and the rest of the app don't scroll. I can't deactivate the touch since I need it for a div which should be scrollable. This scrollable div is only a part of the app. 
I have tried to set the body's and the root div's height to 548px. But this does not prevent the app from scrolling, and I get a white bande for the area outside the height that I have defined.
Here is a screenshot.
[image: There is a white bande at the bottom]

Any idea on how I could define the height of the root div in order that its height corresponds to exactly the rest height of the screen (that is to say, 568px-20px=548px, on iphone 5) so it doesn't scroll. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First you need to set UIWebViewBounce:No to cordova.plist file
then set your body height/width according to screen size give it dynamically if possible. you can use $(window).height(), $(window).width() to get screen size dynamically

Comment: I think I have done that already. I have set the height of body to 548px since the height of status bar is 20px and the length of iphone5 is 568px.